# JQuery dialog positioning jumps down when position top is specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to get my jquery dialog position all the way on top of everything left corner. My dialog definition:

```
$('#my_dialog').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: false, 
   draggable: false,
   show: 'slide',
   hide: 'slide',
   position: {
     of: $(document),
     my: 'left top',
     at: 'left top',
     collision: 'none'
   }
   ...
});
```

now when dialog is opened it opens on top but then jumps all the way on the bottom. Please help is there other way of doing this ?

EDIT: the way i open the dialog is:

```
$('#my_dialog').parent().effect("bounce", {}, "fast");
$('#my_dialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: using bounce effect and then dialog open

Comment: Why not `$('#my_dialog').dialog('open');`?

Comment: i want it to bounce when opened its kind of an alert

Comment: Can you replicate it? http://jsfiddle.net/RYdbX/

Comment: try running same js when window is long and you scrolled in the middle. If dialog opens while you are in the middle of the screen it opens in the middle instead of opening it on top

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the effect... you are applying it to the dialog before the dialog is made visible. Simply reverse these two lines, and you should get the desired outcome:

```
$('#my_dialog').dialog('open');
$('#my_dialog').parent().effect("bounce", {}, "fast");
```